# Dart (Flutter) JSON to object script, json2builtvalue output missing Builders and serializers

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I watched the [Flutter Boring Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fahC3ky_zW0&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIK0r_D-zWcmJ1plIcDNnRkK&index=5) and saw a great tool, [json2builtvalue](https://charafau.github.io/json2builtvalue/).

When I used it to generate a dart object, and copied/pasted the output into my project, I got a number of errors.  Specifically for missing builders and a missing serializers error, and unfortunately there isn't a lot of help on how to use it if you just go to the json2builtvalue site.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is actually built on top of [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/example/lib/serializers.dart).  For that you have to include the appropriate dependencies in your project.

```
built_value: ^6.5.0
built_collection: '>=2.0.0 <5.0.0'
```

Next, I had to create a 'serializers.dart' file. (I placed mine in the 'lib' folder.)

```
library serializers;

import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';

part 'serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor([
  MyClass1,
  MyClass2
])

final Serializers serializers = _$serializers;
```

Then I had to run a script to generate the missing builders, which required me to update my dev_dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  built_value_generator: ^6.5.0
```

Finally I had to run the script:

```
 flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking to use it.